# Java NoSuchMethodError for javax.swing.JDialog.setAutoRequestFocus from Command Line

Tags: java, netbeans, nosuchmethod

In cmd or Powershell, I do java -jar file.jar (javaw doesn't return anything, but also, doesn't run the program).

It uses swing, and when I run it:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.swing.JDialog.setAutoRequestFocus(Z)V
        at file.fileView.initComponents(fileView.java:852)
        at file.fileView.<init>(fileView.java:42)
        at file.fileApp.startup(fileApp.java:50)
        at org.jdesktop.application.Application$1.run(Application.java:171)
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

It says that their is no such method of .requestFocus.

This was auto-generated with Netbeans, and it works fine in Netbeans.  However, it doesn't in the cmd/powershell.

Thanks,

Justin W.

Comment: Which JDK/JRE are you using in netbeans, and which are you using from the command line?

Comment: What is the V symbol at the end of the first line?

Comment: @AdelBoutros: the `V` signifies that the method returns `void`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are using the java 7 in netbeans and you are using an older version of java from the command line.  `setAutoRequestFocus` is new to java 7.